# If $\dim (\operatorname{Ker}f)^{\perp} = 1$ then $f$ is continuous for $f$ linear functional on Hilbert space

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, orthogonality

I need to prove the following result:

> If $\dim (\operatorname{Ker}f)^{\perp} = 1$ then $f$ is continuous for $f$ linear
>   functional on Hilbert space.

I have the following ingredients in mind:

- Use sequential characterization of continuity knowing that since $\operatorname{Ker}(f)$ is closed, projection theorem gives that $x_n = m_n + u_n \to x = m + u$ is equivalent to $m_n \to m \land u_n \to u$.
- Someone suggested me to further prove that $H = \operatorname{Ker}(f) \oplus \operatorname{Ker}(f)^{\perp} = \operatorname{Ker}(f) \oplus\operatorname{Img}(f)$ but I don't see how this is of any help.

Any ideas?

Comment: Let $0\neq y\in(Ker(f))^{\bot}$. Then $f(y)\neq0$. If $x\in ((Ker(f))^{\bot})^{\bot}$, then $f(x)=0$. In fact, if $f(x)\neq0$ then $y-\frac{f(y)}{f(x)}x$ would be in the kernel and in particular in $((Ker(f))^{\bot})^{\bot}$ which is impossible, because it would imply that $y\in((Ker(f))^{\bot})^{\bot}$. Therefore $Ker(f)=((Ker(f))^{\bot})^{\bot}$, which is closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $\dim(Ker(f)^{\perp})=1$, where $f$ is a linear functional. Then there exists a unit vector $x$ such that $x\perp Ker(f)$. In particular $f(x)\ne 0$. So,
$$
        f\left(y-\frac{f(y)}{f(x)}x\right) = 0,
$$
which forces the following for all $y$:
$$
             \left\langle y-\frac{f(y)}{f(x)}x,x\right\rangle = 0 \\
           \langle y,x\rangle = \frac{f(y)}{f(x)} \\
        f(y) = \langle y,\overline{f(x)}x\rangle,\;\; y\in H.
$$
So $f$ is a continuous linear functional because it has a Riesz representation.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this is obvious, but it does not leap out at me that $\ker f$ is closed.

This is essentially @orole's argument in the comment above.

For example, if we take $A \subset l_2$ to the the subspace generated by
elements of the form $(0,x_2,x_3,...,x_n,0,0,...)$, then $A^\bot = \operatorname{sp} \{ e_1\}$, but while $A \subset A^{\bot \bot}$, they are
clearly not equal.

Suppose $\phi:\mathbb{H} \to \mathbb{R}^n$ is linear and $\dim (\ker \phi)^\bot = n$,
then $\ker \phi$ is closed.

Let $y_1,...,y_n$ be a basis for $(\ker \phi)^\bot$. Then $\phi (y_1),...,\phi (y_n)$ are linearly independent and hence span ${\cal R} \phi$.

Let $z \in (\ker \phi)^{\bot \bot}$. Choose
$\alpha_k$
such that $\phi(z) = \phi (\sum_k \alpha_k y_k)$, then
$z-\sum_k \alpha_k y_k \in \ker \phi \subset (\ker \phi)^{\bot \bot}$. Since
$z \in (\ker \phi)^{\bot \bot}$ this gives $\sum_k \alpha_k y_k \in  (\ker \phi)^{\bot \bot}$ and hence $\sum_k \alpha_k y_k = 0$ and so $\phi(z) = 0$,
or $ z \in \ker \phi$. Hence $\ker \phi$ is closed (and so $\phi$ is continuous).

(Looking back, it would have sufficed to do this for $n=1$.)

Answer (score -1):

Let $x$ non zero in the orhogonal of $Ker(f)$, the linear function $\langle x, .\rangle$ is continuous, this implies that its kernel $Ker(f)$ is closed and $f$ is continuous.

[Closed kernel implies continuous linear functional : Zorn's Lemma](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2327189/closed-kernel-implies-continuous-linear-functional-zorns-lemma/2327244)

Comment: Why is $\ker f$ closed?

Comment: because it is the kernel of $f(y)=\langle x,y\rangle$

Comment: You haven't proved that.

Comment: I have proven what ?

Comment: That $\ker f$ is closed.

Comment: That $f(y)=(x,y)$ ... which is even false for the arbitrary $x\in (Ker(f))^{\bot}$ that you chose.

Comment: the kernel of a continuous linear function is closed you really need a proof for that

Comment: $\ker f$ is clearly contained in $\{x\}^\bot$ which is closed, but that does not imply that $\ker f$ is closed.

Comment: I have never said that $f(x)=(x,y)$, but if $x\neq 0$, $(x,y)=0$ if and only if $x\in $ the orthogonal of $x$ which is $ker f$ here

Comment: read the question: the rthogonal of $ker f$ is $vect(x)$ since it is $1$ dimensional

Comment: That is what you need to prove, that the elements of $\{x\}^{\bot}$ are all in the kernel, which you don't.

Comment: You have not shown that $\{x\}^\bot = \ker f$. It is true that $\overline{A} \subset A^{\bot \bot}$ but the issue here is equality.

Comment: excuse me, i want argue anymore with you,...

Comment: It is not an argument, it is a request for clarification.

Comment: Oh my. Now I remember. You are the guy that had an embedded manifold and was proving that it didn't have tangent space. These comments won't get anywhere. Never mind, enjoy your imaginary proof.

Comment: Please for the last time, review your course on Hilbert space, in particular the chapter about orthogonal projection, to figure out WHY the orthogonal of $x$ is $ker(f)$, I cannot help you more unfortunately, but this are the very basic of the theory.

Comment: @Tsemo, as others have tried to make you noticed, what you wrote depends on showing that «this implies that the kernel $Ker(f)$ is closed»: you have not explained in what way *this* implies that. Indeed, your setup implies that $Ker(f)$ is contained in the kernel of $(x,\cdot)$ and the latter is closed: how do you deduce that $Ker(f)$ itself is closed?

Comment: $Kerf$ is the kernel of $g=<x,.>$ i.e, $Kerf=g^{-1}(0)$ and $g$ is continuous.

Comment: The problem is precisely in that you need to show somehow that the kernel of $f$ coincides with the kernel of $\langle x,\cdot\rangle$.